# how to get hour from timestamp and attonate it and count its number of occurances in django

Tags: django, django-models, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a "startTime" field in my model which contains timestamp.I want to get a list with count of only hour from that stamp.I mean my code should be able convert and get only hour from the timestamp and count the number of occurance of each hour.I tried doing

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(<timestamp>)).strftime(\'%H\'))
```

this thing returns only hour from a timestamp but when i tried incorporating it in the queryset..it failed..this is what i tried in my views.py

```
 timehour = InteractionWith.objects \
    .values('startTime')\
    .annotate(times=Count('datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("startTime")).strftime(\'%H\'))'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the queryset with [**`ExtractHour`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractHour):

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour

timehour = InteractionWith.objects.values(
    hour=ExtractHour('startTime')
).annotate(
    times=Count('pk')
).order_by('hour')
```

Comment: it says "ValueError at /
Extract input expression must be DateField, DateTimeField, TimeField, or DurationField."         i think its cuz startTime is still a Timestamp

Comment: @VivekAnand: then `startTIme` is *not* a `DateTimeField` (or a `TimeField`)? Please make it a `DateTimeField` (or `TimeField`). By using text you allow all sorts of (invalid) values: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField

Comment: van : Datetimefield accepts PSOiX format timestamp whereas mine is a unix timestamp.that is why i was using datetime.datetime().....is there any way to convert (unix timestamp to extract hour) it at the time of query

Comment: @VivekAnand: isn't Unix time and POSIX time the same? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time and https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: i made a datetimefield and now instead of asking for a single timestamp input it asks form both date and time

Comment: @VivekAnand: you can use a different widget for that. For example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.NumberInput